# Visual Studio 2019 C6385 / C6386 (buffer overrun warning) on __m256 array

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-warnings, visual-studio-2019

I'm allocating an array as follows:

`__m256 *v256f_valid_mask = (__m256*)malloc(sizeof(__m256) * p_ranks);`

The compiler is showing warning C6385 / C6386 (depending on exact context) on all lines where I access this array, except for at `[0]`, indicating that 64 bytes may be read. The definition clearly states it's an array of 32-byte values.

Using `_aligned_malloc()` doesn't help.

Sample code to reproduce the warning:

```
void func(const size_t p_ranks)
{
    __m256 v256f_x = _mm256_set1_ps(1.0f);
    __m256* v256f_valid_mask = (__m256*)malloc(sizeof(__m256) * p_ranks);

    for (size_t rank = 1; rank < p_ranks; rank++)
    {
        v256f_valid_mask[rank] = _mm256_cmp_ps(v256f_x, _mm256_setzero_ps(), _CMP_GT_OQ); // <<
    }
}
```

Exact warning:

[image]

I fixed the C6011 warning with a null check.

Is there an error in my code or is this a false positive?

Comment: It would help if you provided the full text of the diagnostic.  As it is you only get answers from anyone who is familiar with the the error code or takes the _trouble_ to look it up (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/c6385?view=vs-2019).

Comment: It is not possible to "reproduce the warning" with the _"sample code to reproduce the warning"_ as it is incomplete and includes references to symbols not available to us.  That is simply _the code that generated the warning_ - which is not the same thing, and not nearly so useful.

Comment: @Clifford, I've edited the code to only contain the problematic line. It should now reproduce the warning.

Comment: What type is `p_ranks` and what value is it?

Comment: Latest stable VS2019, ran code analysis on solution, no warnings at all, https://imgur.com/a/hw24HCh If I set `v256f_valid_mask` to 0 instead of malloc'ing a value it complains about it, so code analysis is working...

Comment: And with all warnings https://imgur.com/a/HSIMUZN

Comment: You missed my point. It is not possible for a reader to _reproduce_ the error using incomplete code.  Moreover, you continue to omit the diagnostic text - preferring to _describe_ it that her than copy & paste it verbatim.

Comment: It appears that @ta.speot.is recognised the functions and types you are using and _can_ at least incorporate your code fragment into something compilable (but not reproducing the error), but nothing in your question provides that information; he has had to rely on superior knowledge. This unnecessarily reduces the audience that may be able to assist.

Comment: @Clifford I wrapped the code into a function and copied a screen shot of the warning.

Comment: It is not a compile error, merely a code analysis warning. It *would* be valid if the statement actually copied 64 bytes, but of course it doesn't.  Pretty plain bug.  Use Help > Send Feedback > Report a Bug to tell them about it.  And disable the warning to keep going.  Favor the [visual-c++] tag to avoid these kind of comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a false positive but the code analyser doesn't know it (probably because it doesn't 'trust' the malloc() call)! Using 'new' instead clears the warning (at least, in my VS2019 solution) …

```
void func(const size_t p_ranks)
{
    __m256 v256f_x = _mm256_set1_ps(1.0f);
//  __m256* v256f_valid_mask = (__m256*)malloc(sizeof(__m256) * p_ranks);
    #if defined(__cplusplus)
    __m256* v256f_valid_mask = new __m256[p_ranks];
    #else
    #define MAXRANKS 100 // Would probably be defined elsewhere!
    __m256 v256f_valid_mask[MAXRANKS];
    #endif

    for (size_t rank = 1; rank < p_ranks; rank++)
    {
        v256f_valid_mask[rank] = _mm256_cmp_ps(v256f_x, _mm256_setzero_ps(), _CMP_GT_OQ); // <<
    }
}
```

Please try and see!

Comment: The question is tagged as `c` ... how do you use `new` from `c`?

Comment: @ta.speot.is: Interesting point! See edit in code block with an UGLY solution for plain old C!